# Do I need to set metadata in app when publish app to app store

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

I'am in phase of setting my app for my first app submit to app store.
I saw this:

> Before you submit your application, it is a good idea to have your
>   application’s metadata at hand. This includes (1) your application’s
>   name, (2) the version number, (3) the primary (and an optional
>   secondary) category, (4) a concise description, (5) keywords, and (6)
>   a support URL.

My question is **do I need to set this metadata somewhere in my xcode project and where?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the Meta data is all the data including (1) your application’s name, (2) the version number, (3) the primary (and an optional secondary) category, (4) a concise description, (5) keywords, and (6) a support URL etc which you should know for uploading an app to the Apple Store. You will have to use this information while uploading.

[Supplying information](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-supply-information-for-your-ipad-app-to-the.html) to the App store can be done once you have collected all the data.

I think you should go through this tutorial on [how to submit an App](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/how-to-submit-an-ios-app-to-the-app-store/) to the Apple store.

**EDIT :**

The **Metadata** has ***nothing*** to do with the xcode project or the .plist file whatsoever. You **DONT** have to do anything with it. This information you have to enter in the website of the Apple store when they ask for it .

[image]

Comment: That is tutorial I follow and I stuck on "Step 3: Metadata".
So do I add this information somewhere in XCode info.plist... or during upload app to appstore it will ask for this information?

Comment: no need to add these in app's plist, only in itunesconnect. one exception is version number which should match app's version with itunesconnect version.

Comment: 'one exception is version number' sorry I didn't see this, is this number is in info.plist?

Comment: In which context are you referring this ?

Comment: Where do I set this number?